# Prove an upper and lower bound for D(a,b).

Tags: graph-theory

Let D(a,b) be the smallest integer such that every directed complete graph on D(a,b) vertices either has a totally ordered a-clique, or b edge-disjoint directed 3-cycles. Prove an upper and lower bound for D(a,b).

I dont really know how to start here.